# How to Create Thumbnails of Video at runtime using PHP,Java,.Net?

Tags: c#, php, .net, video, thumbnails

is it possible to create video thumnails at runtime in any of the technology (Java,PHP,.Net).

Please provide the suitable link or code if you have any

Thanks in advance

Comment: A magic: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=create+video+thumbnail

Comment: to create thumbnail, you have to use List and then xml file to populate it with the files in the list and at the end you specify the dimensions of the thumbnail, you can use ajax which is a plus.

Comment: actually guys i am asking for the library functions which can be used to create thumnails from the video passed as parameters.

Answer (score -1):

his is the list to be populated:

```
 List<ThumbNail> thmbNails = new List<ThumbNail>();// your list which will hold thumbnails
CMESqlCommandBuilder iscBuilder = new CMESqlCommandBuilder(); //query of the d.b
while (sdaResult.Read()) // while loop if you want more than one video thumbanil on page
            {
                ThumbNail prd = new ThumbNail();
return thumbnails; // this will goes to the xml file which.
```

I hope this will give you an idea. how to do it.
I write the code short but i hope this how it will look and work.

Comment: -1 This code doesn't do anything (no code is called to produce thumbnails of videos, e.g. video parsing, image creation, etc.). Classes such as ThumbNail and CMESqlCommandBuilder are not defined anywhere, nor are they standard classes. The brackets are not matched in the while. In short, this code will not help anyone create thumbnails.

Comment: @ Adrian Smith: Thanks but as far i understand the question this comes to my mind, and i have implemented to create thumbnail of mp3 and video file on website, and they are stored either physical file system or DB. So i just write how it can be. i did not write the complete code. I will consider your remarks and i hope this will give me much good ideas. Have nice day.

Comment: Actually i was asking for any library function if exists , whose work is to create thumbnails from the video passed to the function as parmaeters.